# Saving the displayed/filtered packets in wireshark

Tags: networking, wireshark, tcpdump

I applied a filter in wireshark to display only the incoming packets to my PC. When I save the filtered/displayed packets to a .csv file, I actually saves all the packets (un-filtered). How can I save only the displayed/filtered packets?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

[Exporting data](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChIOExportSection.html)
Just select Displayed in the [Packet Range](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChIOPacketRangeSection.html) frame.

Note that with newer builds of Wireshark for Windows, this is available only with "Export Specified Packets", not with "Save" or "Save as" options.

Comment: Actually, if you want to minimize the temporary file, you could add a filter to the capture itself: Capture -> Options -> Capture filter "host 192.168.1.1" (or whatever is the IP you want to filter.

Comment: @joke - How to save to file the displayed output using tcpdump? (in my case the -w save every thing)

Comment: I found it - #>tcpdump > file

Comment: Their website says to use the Save All option in the dialog. This is a lie. Use the Export function.

Comment: It is in "File" ->"Export Specified Packets..." for Linux version. Running wireshark 2.2.6 on Debian Testing here.